# The "@" syntax in solidity import statement not working

Tags: import, solidity, remix

I am trying to run a smart contract using the [Chainlink](https://docs.chain.link/docs) documentation, and I ran into this while testing in remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
```

I'm assuming this import should be

`import "github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol"`

How do I get this `@` syntax to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Remix, you should use:

```
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
```

For local development, you should use:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
```

Based on: https://docs.chain.link/docs/create-a-chainlinked-project

The difference is the `@chainlink` package is published to [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chainlink/contracts), while Remix can use the URL to the [contract directly](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol).